# Protractor asynchronous parallel testing on docker containers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

for few days i struggle with parallel execution of tests using selenium docker.

Following scenario:

- Define browsers in multiCapabilities with specs.
- Deploy containers with selenium-hub, 2 firefox, 2 chrome nodes.
- Run tests

Issues is appearing when, chrome and firefox are running the same spec in parallel.
Depending on the speed of execution, lets say if firefox is first and chrome second. (spec1 is running on both browsers at the same time).

Due dependency spec1 is successful on firefox (as expected) and on chrome it should fail with exception (as expected). Here it goes the interesting part:

**firefox test ending, but chrome is hanging (the part where it throw exception) and test fails after the configured jasmine/test timeout, lets say 3 minutes with 
"*unresolved promise*"....** 
Since i have await on the method, and i have wrapped it in try catch, the exception should go up to the test, where i have also wrap the test methods in try catch, and if there is an exception done.fail() should stop the test.

But it never goes to there... after long time of debugging, the only thing i can see its that exception is thrown and it never goes to the test where i should catch it and fail the test.

Configuration of multicapabilities

```
{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2,
    specs: [
        '../spec/**/spec1.js'
    ]
},
    {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    maxInstances: 2,
    shardTestFiles: true,
    marionette: true,
    specs: [
        '../spec/**/spec1.js'
    ]
},
```

Protractor specific:

```
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    seleniumAddress: 'ip of the selenium hub'
    maxSessions: 4
    framework: 'jasmine'
    ... and other custom not related props as loggers, reporters etc.
```

Test example:

```
describe('test 1', () => {

    it('can done something', async (done) => {
        try {
            await doSomething();
        } catch (e) {
            done.fail(e);
        }

        done();
    }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
}
```

if there is an exception from doSomething(), test should be forced to fail, but it hangs in parallel execution.

Do i miss something and/or can you suggest why it hangs, while executing the same test on different browsers?

If you need some more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of callbacks does not work with async. If you want to fail test you can do it easier:

```
describe('test 1', () => {

    it('can done something', async () => {
        try {
            await doSomething();
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I highly recommend to use [Selenoid](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid) for running e2e tests in containers.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, but you are not correct they are working pretty fine, since jasmine stop the task and mark test as failure if done.fail() is called. The problem is test stack do not reach this point.it just timeout from jasmine defaul timeout config.

Comment: could you try to re-write without `done` things? ;) I just wonder how it would work with `throw new Error(e)`